# Blurry images in Volley's NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a list with items containing a `NetworkImageView` and I am facing a strange bug. I want to be able to remove the list item using a swipe gesture, so I am using the [EnhancedListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView) library. The problem is that when I delete an item in the list using the swipe gesture, the image in the `NetworkImageView` gets blurry.

A screenshot of the list before the item removal can be found [here](http://i60.tinypic.com/ftq0ww.jpg) and a screenshot of the list after the first element has been removed using a swipe gesture can be found [here](http://i57.tinypic.com/4rxs20.jpg).

The problem occurs when the view of the item gets recycled in the adapter. If I don't use a `ViewHolder` and inflate the layout every time in `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, the problem does not occur (even though the list flickers after an item removal in that case).

Here is the code in the fragment that sets up the removal of elements using the swipe gesture:

```
mListView.setDismissCallback(new de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView.OnDismissCallback() {
    @Override
    public EnhancedListView.Undoable onDismiss(EnhancedListView listView, final int position) {
        final Cafe cafe = mAdapter.getItem(position);
        mAdapter.removeAt(position);
        return new EnhancedListView.Undoable() {
            /**
             * This method is called if undo button is pressed
             */
            @Override
            public void undo() {
                mAdapter.insertAt(position, cafe);
            }

            /**
             * Returns the text in the Toast next to "Undo"
             * @return text
             */
            @Override public String getTitle() {
                return getString(R.string.removed_from_favorites);
            }

            /**
             * This method is called after the undo text has been discarded.
             * It must remove the favorite in the model.
             */
            @Override public void discard() {
                CafeHelper.getInstance().toggleCafeStarredStatus(cafe.getId());
            }
        };
    }
});

mListView.enableSwipeToDismiss();
mListView.setSwipeDirection(EnhancedListView.SwipeDirection.START);
```

You can see that the swipe gesture simply calls `mAdapter.removeAt(position);`. Here is the code of the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method and the definition of the `ViewHolder` in the adapter:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    NetworkImageView image;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_starred_cafe_list_item, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.starred_cafe_list_item_name);
        viewHolder.image = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.starred_cafe_list_item_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.image.setImageUrl(null, VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader());
    }
    Cafe cafe = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.name.setText(cafe.getName());
    viewHolder.image.setImageUrl(cafe.getThumbUrl(), VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader());

    return convertView;
}
```

Notes:

- The adapter is a custom adapter based on a [StableArrayAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/jb-mr1-dev/samples/devbytes/animation/ListViewRemovalAnimation/src/com/example/android/listviewremovalanimation/StableArrayAdapter.java). I also tried with a normal `ArrayAdapter` and the same problem occurs. I really doubt the problem is related to the adapter.
- I also tried [android-swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) as the library to implement the swipe to remove feature. The exact same problem occurs. That's what lead me to believe that the bug is related to Volley rather than to the swipe library.
- Simply calling `mAdapter.removeAt(position);` without using a swipe to remove library works flawlessly.
- Using an `ImageView` with [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load the image works without any problem.
- I am using Volley as a Singleton using the Application context.

After digging in Volley's code, it seems that the problem might be related to getting the width and height of the `NetworkImageView`, but I haven't had time to debug the library. If anyone with a deep understanding of Volley can help pinpointing the problem and finding a solution, your answers are welcome.

Comment: I am experiencing same problem. I am using vector drawable as default image for NetworkImageView, but it shows blurry often. After single tap it becomes clear.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where the loaded images were blurry and i think it was caused by the layout property:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

By replacing it with the line below resolved it:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

I think you're right and Volley can only get the original width of the image and NOT the width after some sort of adjustements